# Modify godot engine's source code , but not reflecting the modified changes on android apk

Tags: godot

My development environment  is on Ubuntu. godot version is v4.1-stable.

I add some print_line code and assert on the engine's source code,

I wan to export android apk to view my add print_line log,

[so i reference this page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html#doc-android-setting-up-the-buildsystem)

I generate android template then godot editor > export  > Custom page reference android_debug.apk and android_release.apk.

Finally, I build and generate Android apk is success, and install on device.

But not triggered my add print_line and assert code (i'm sure these logs and assert should be definitely be triggered),

It's as if nothing happened at all.

Can tell me if i modify engine code, the correct build process for build an android app?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem.

Build android template and move android_debug.apk/android_release.apk/android_source.zip file to $HOME/.local/share/godot/export_templates//

When using the custom build system, have to Delete the android/build folder and android/.build_version files and re-install them using the new build you created.